# android layout: how to put multi control in a layout, show 3 control each line

Tags: android, layout

I want to design a layout to select cities. 3 city a line(It may be multiline). The control that indicate city may be textview, button or others. And I need to add city easily. which layout should I use and how can I config it correctly?

I have a idea that use a vertical linearlayout and a horizonal linearlayout to do that. but it's so complex and hard to add city dynamicly.

Comment: Your question requires restating. It's hard to determine your exact request. "3 city a line, and multi lines." A horizontal `LinearLayout` with 3 children that define equal weights would give you 3 balanced `View`s at any screen width (you would ideally still need to handle things like increasing padding or changing layouts to provide the best experience throughout). Maybe add the XML layout you are considering and/or a picture/sketch of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thank u for your reply. 3 city a line, and count of city may be more than 3, so multi lines required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a `GridView` with `android:numColumns` set to 3. This way you should get a maximum of three city elements on a horizontal line and the amount of lines would increment as the amount of city elements grows.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: I would change `GridView` to `GridLayout`, since he wants a layout of controls, and not a "list" of items. But that is a way to layout.

Comment: He also stated the need to easily add more city elements later, so the use of GridView with an adapter would serve the purpose quite well.

Comment: add more elements with a `GridLayout`, you can dynamically control a layout.

Comment: As GridLayout requires API level 14 or higher and my application need support Android 2.2(API level 8), i finally use GridView instead of GridLayout.